# Alembic Error: "Only a single head supported so far..."

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

When running the alembic `revision` command to generate a new revision script I get the following (not particularly helpful) error:

```
 $ alembic -c <my-config>.ini revision -m "example message"
   Only a single head supported so far...
```

The implication seems to be I somehow ended up with two `HEAD`s in my Alembic system--although I'm not really certain what this means.

In our workflow migration scripts are written by multiple developers so my guess would be somehow two developers concurrently created a revision which refers to the same "revises" identifier.

- Is that what this error message means?
- What is the best way to identify the offending migration scripts?
- What is the best way to fix this error (keeping in mind that I believe all migrations in our version control have been applied to the DB already)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you have two revisions referencing the same `down_revision`. Just look at the last few revisions you've created and see which ones reference the same `down_revision`.

```
# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '234342f7fc2d'
down_revision = '3981426f2c20'
```

My offending revision ended up being an "extra" un-used one, so I just deleted it.